# Smart way to convert child objects property name, into string array?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an object similar to this:

```
{
    "name":"sdfsd",
    "id":1,
    "groups":[
        {
            "name":"name1",
            "id":1,
            "subGroups":[..]
        },
        {
            "name":"name2",
            "id":21,
            "subGroups":[..]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want an array with following:

```
[
   {
      "name":"name1",
      "id":1
   },
   {
      "name":"name2",
      "id":21
   }
]
```

I could just make a loop, and create my array, but there must be a more beautiful way in ES6?

Comment: What is about using something like `yourObject.groups.map(group => ({name: group.name, id: group.id}))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write:

```
const groups = this.obj.groups.map( ({name, id}) => ({name, id}) );
```

Or encapsulate mapper into separate function like this:

```
const getNameId = ({name, id}) => ({name, id});
const groups = this.obj.groups.map(getNameId);
```

So you use a lot of ES6 features here:

- map() function - introduced before ES6 but a very functional way for mapping over existing array and creating a new one in an immutable way (deep copy, no reference to original array)
- destructuring objects as function parameters --> `({name, id}) =>` read about it - it's awesome.
- object shorthand notation --> `=> ({name, id})`
- point free notation - another feature favoured by functional programming enthusiast - you can use it with `unary` functions - functions with only one parameter, also called as having `arity` of 1. So insted of writing 
  `groups.map(g => ({id: g.id, name: g.name}))` you extract mapper function into separate function and then pass it in like this `map(getNameId)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.map()` array method:

```
const groups = myObject.groups.map(g => ({ name : g.name, id : g.id }) );
```

Answer (score 1):

a clean ES6 way:

```
let groups = this.obj['groups'].map( ({id, name}) => ({ id, name }) );
```

or you can make it even cleaner with [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
let groups = this.obj['groups'].map( ({subGroups, ...groups}) => (groups) );
```

Comment: You can shorten this a bit using property name punning, which reduces the risk of introducing a typo in the property names in the new object: `let groups = this.obj.groups.map( ({ id, name }) => ({ id, name }) );`

Comment: Ohh guys so many good suggestions. Thanks all! Seems like you only can mark one answer, a shame where there is multiple good answers. Personally I prefer this one: const groups = myObject.groups.map(g => ({ name : g.name, id : g.id }) );